# Display limited data in mvc 4 view from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-pagination

I am developing a online books shopping website and  in this I display the books and their description on a view that is dynamically generated from database.
But I want to show 10 books per page and a link on bottom of page to go to next page to see next 10 books.
here I am attaching my code it fetch all data from database and show all books at atime in a single page. How I implement paging functionality in this..

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
@model IEnumerable<BusinessObject.Images>

<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="content">
<!-- Products -->
            <div class="products">
                <h3>Featured Products</h3>
                <ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{



                    <li>
                        <div class="product">
                        @Html.ActionLink(item.ImageName, "Details","Home", new { id = item.ImageId }, null) 

                                <span class="holder">
                                    <img src="@item.ImagePath" alt="">
                                    <span class="@item.ImageName" >@item.ImageName</span>
                                    <span class="author">by John Smith</span>
                                    <span class="description">Maecenas vehicula ante eu enim pharetra<br />scelerisque dignissim <br />sollicitudin nisi</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="buy-btn">BUY NOW <span class="price"><span class="low">$</span>22<span class="high">00</span></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>}
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request for only the required number of records from your database itself - Pagination

Check the link

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1699/sql-server-stored-procedures-to-page-large-tables-or-queries/

Comment: so if you've a 100 books, you can get them 5 at a time / 10 at a time - whatever

Comment: On your first page display the 1st ten books ( you can even get them by sorting them based on filters) .. on clicking next , you can get the next 10 results ..
If you have say 50,000 books, you don't have to fetch them at once, you can fetch them as and when the user requests them ..